# Solidity/Truffle - Suddenly getting TypeError on Migration file

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle

Suddenly getting an error when doing a `truffle compile --reset` - even though I didn't make *any* code changes on my `Migrations.sol` file.

```
TypeError: Name has to refer to a struct, enum or contract.
    Migrations upgraded = Migrations(new_address);
```

I mean I get that the contract's name *is* `Migrations`, but this was always the case. Why is this suddenly happening *now* is what I'd like to know. And how do you fix it?

Its especially weird given that this `Migrations.sol` file wasn't even written by me, as its automatically provided when you create a new project.

(Would this have anything to do with the new version of Truffle - meaning 5.0.2?)

Comment: You're not telling us everything. By moving from Truffle 4.x to Truffle 5.x, you have essentially updated the compiler version from 0.4.x to 0.5.x. This by itself should have given you a single error for each one of your sol files: `SyntaxError: Source file requires different compiler version`. So you have by the least changed the `pragma` statement in your `Migrations.sol` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this error only with solidity 0.5.x, so I am guessing that you're using truffle 5.x. You can check the version by calling `truffle version`

Actually you should see three errors

- SyntaxError: Source file requires different compiler version
- SyntaxError: Functions are not allowed to have the same name as the contract.
- TypeError: Name has to refer to a struct, enum or contract.

The last one is a consequential error due to the first two. So if you fix the pragma and constructor it should disappear.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract ... {
    ...
    constructor() public {
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```